# Is this considered double spend?

Tags: blockchain.info, doublespend

I had a [Receive](https://blockchain.info/tx/e2049965d518a60d95ddb997984e3ea3adc4aa7340d0a7dde1d36aea70eec3c3) transaction worth 0.185btc

I was confident that it was ok since I saw 5 confirmation before I close the wallet.

The next day when I checked I saw a sent transaction with 0.185 btc which I didn't authorized. When I click the link it showed me this [Sent](https://blockchain.info/tx/02fe5f19fcf4268fcfeb2f8e4a96f697dd0a561c334f6225a4a4b09f5b69eba1) transaction.

The weird part is it says that the output is 1btc which I didn't have because I only have 0.185 btc on that wallet.

[image: Blockchain]

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't a double spend, I'm sorry to say, but it looks like your bitcoin was stolen.

The reason the transaction out says '1 BTC' is that your bitcoin was combined with bitcoin from a bunch of other addresses, and sent all together to that new address.

You'll have to carefully think about how this might have happened. If your wallet was backed up by email, it may simply be that your email account was compromised.

Again, sorry for your losses :(

Comment: Just as I suspected. I'll investigate further how my account was compromised. This has been an expensive lesson learned. Thanks for the response.